# GWT file upload to local system

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I am new to GWT, and trying to understand how the gwt upload works. I am using this link to learn about how to upload files. This is the client side code.

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FileUpload

However, I have no idea about the servlets and how they work. What if I wanted to upload files to a local directory on my system, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_fileupload_widget.htm this may help you

Comment: But I think it still doesnt tell me if I can upload files to my local drive.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "local drive"?

Comment: Its just to to check, if I can 'upload' files to my hard drive as well! Other than that, I want to know how to create a local server, what a servlet actually is, and upload files to that.

Comment: Well, if you've got a web server on the machine you want to upload files to, then yes.

Comment: Could you recommend me to some tutorial on how to get the web server on my machine ?

Comment: [Tomcat 8](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

What is the use case behind what you try to accomplish? I.e. what makes you want to upload files to a local directoy?

As Baz says: what do you mean with "local"? Do you mean local to the browser?

If so, that is normally not allowed directly as it violates the browser "sandbox". Upload means upload to a server, which normally is a different system than where the browser runs. Than again if you do run the server locally (i.e. on the same machine as the browser) you can get access the local resources via the server.

So... not sure if I understand what you try to accomplish. Or is it more for educational purposes and trying to learn client-server communication?

See also e.g. [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)